# Now.js Uncaught TypeError: Object#<Object>

Tags: javascript, object, node.js, typeerror, nowjs-sockets

I downloaded the example project from Now.js http://nowjs.com/guide
and when I run it I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'distributeMessage'

after attempting to send a message.

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue with the PaaS not supporting websockets. Solution was just to explicitly disable them, via something like the following:

```
nowjs.initialize(server, {socketio: {transports: ['xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling', 'htmlfile']}});
```

(resolved in #nowjs IRC)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard for us to know with so little information.  If you post your code, we are more likely to know what's going on.

Looking at the hello world demo on the nowjs.com site, it looks like maybe you don't have the `helloworld_server.js` file included in your page because that's where the `distributeMessage()` function is defined.

In the demo files [here](https://github.com/downloads/Flotype/now/chat-example.tgz), helloworld.html has this line:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/nowjs/now.js"></script>
```

But, the demo tgz file doesn't include that.  You are probably missing `now.js` in an appropriate path.

Comment: er, this is node, so the helloworld_server is actually calling the html, and with now, it should be defined... no?

Comment: You can download the exact files I have here: https://github.com/downloads/Flotype/now/chat-example.tgz

Comment: I looked at the demo .tgz and added some comments to my answer based on what I see there.

Comment: I honestly don't think thats it. When I do it in that format, it gives me errors saying it cannot find now.js..

Comment: Also, other now functions work fine, this error is only found when using distributeMessage. Like now.name works fine